# href Links not working

Tags: href

I have a web page I have been working on, Header, Nav panel and Main
the links in the nav panel don't work when the full site is up, but if I load
just the nav page the links work ( Contact )
this is just one of the links, I feel like an idiot, not being able to figure this out

Graham

Comment: " <a target="main" href="Contact.htm">Contact</a> "

Comment: Can you provide some of your work (code) here? It's difficult to provide an answer just reading the question.

Answer (score -1):

contact.htm is not a complete url. The link must have a base website (ex. http://example.com)

try this:

```
<a target="main" href="http://yourwebsite.com/contact.htm">Contact</a>
```

you can also use the `<base>` tag inside of the `<header>` in order to send all url fragments to a single base.